# Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-virtual-device

I cannot build and run my android project using Eclipse on mac 10.7. The error I receive is

> *Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key*

- Changed the permissions in the ~/.android directory with no success.
- Tried generating another project
- Followed the guide of setting up an SDK and was even successful in a windows environment for my windows terminal at my workplace.
- Installed the packages using AVD and have set the location of my SDK location.
- Added my SDK tools to my $PATH variable.

I also receive another error when I try to Create AVD

> *[2011-10-08 13:42:17 - SDK Manager] Error: null*

What other step have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried generating a new keystore?

Comment: No. I deleted the ~/.android directory and then rebuilt my project. That fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleted the ~/.android directory, re-run AVD manager and then rebuild project.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the directory, re-running the AVD manager, and rebuilding didn't fix this problem for me, and best I can tell, it's related to directory permissions.

When I let the AVD manager or keytool.exe create my `.android` directory, the permissions on the directory were:

```
d---------
```

In my case, I

1. removed the `.android` directory
2. `mkdir .android`
3. build and run.

Since I was running from eclipse with the ADT plugin, it prompted me to create a new virtual Android device (since it stores them in the `.android/avd` directory).  And this time, file permissions on `.android` and everything else came out fine.

Comment: Hi. For me it was not necessary to delete .android folder. I only changed its permissions by executing "sudo chmod -R 777 .android" and after that cleaning my projects on Eclipse removed the errors I was getting. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Was getting Error: null when creating AVD using the OSX Android dev bundle.  Bundle was installed in /dev folder in Desktop folder - /Users/me/Desktop/Dev .
Needed to create .android folder in user folder -  /Users/me/.android .