# I'm doing the "first app" lessons on Android Developers, but the app will not run

Tags: java, android

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

That's the page I'm on.
So far it's been pretty simple, because besides naming the app "My First App", it hasn't had me change a thing.

However, when I click Run or even try to click Run As, Eclipse tells me that there's a error in the project,though the red X is only on the project name, and is nowhere else to be found.

Normally when I have done Java programming, the code where the error was could be found easily, but I can't in here. Furthermore, I don't see why there is an error, seeing as the code in here seems to be a template "Hello World!" app, that I have not altered once.

I've tried starting over again several times, but each time it always tells me that the app can't launch because my "project contains errors".

Comment: Can you tried to clean the project?

Comment: What does Window -> Show View -> Problems say?

Comment: This is the one error I found in the Problems view

Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key

Comment: Also for further information, there is no error code or anything with the pop up. It just tells me simply "Your project contains errors. Please fix them before running your application."

Comment: That's very curious. Eclipse should have generated that automatically for you. Is it possible that your "$HOME/.eclipse" directory is read-only or there's something else keeping Eclipse from creating the debug key? What O/S are you on?

Comment: The error message "project contains errors" often indicates that there is a compile error on one of the java source files.  As suggested in an answer below, try a clean and build.  also, fix errors in your java source (often typing errors for tutorials).

Comment: @gwin003 I tried doing the clean thing. The error disappears until I try running the app again. Then the same error returns.

Comment: @EdwardFalk I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 using the Eclipse that comes with the Android SDK that Google provides

Comment: Excellent. I hate developing under Windows.

Comment: Delete the problem from the Windows -> Show View -> Problems list, restart eclipse and try again.

Comment: @JustinJasmann I restarted it, tried running, and the same popup appeared. checked the problems list and the same problem is back

Comment: This help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698636/error-generating-final-archive-unable-to-get-debug-signature-key

Comment: Ooops; I meant ~/.android, not ~/.eclipse

Comment: @JustinJasmann Yep! Got it.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same prob, it could be from xml files. try to clean the project and if it not work so try to look in string file maby you have  ' (Apostrophe)  char in some string , chack if there is eror in console, if you have error tell as what you see

also look this Q

[unable to get debug signature key for my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155895/unable-to-get-debug-signature-key-for-my-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier and I think it's just a loading issue. Try restarting Eclipse, it worked for me.

Comment: I restarted Eclipse and the problem still comes up

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience. Cleaning the project did it all the good in the world

Comment: I did the clean function and the error disappeared.
however it reappeared when I tried running it again

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the ~/.android directory, re-run AVD manager and then rebuild project.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: you find this in my answer here... unable to get debug signature key for my android application , so why you not chack my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project  Properties -> Android and make sure appropriate target is set.